# Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin with version(>=2022.1222.1)

Tags: macos, xamarin, telerik

We have a Xamarin project, and we need to start debugging on MAC. We use the MacInCloud Service.

After cloning the project from source control, I encounter the following error -> Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin with version(>=2022.1222.1). It appears as soon as the project is cloned and with the the 'Could not restore packages'.

What options do I have to resolve this issue?

I have tried removing the the package from the Packages directory and removed the reference in the csproj aswell.

I can't do a manual install of telerik as we do not have admin rights on MacInCloud.

The log file >This is the entire log file - Getting restore information for project /Users/user219905/Documents/GitHub/gts-mobile/GtsApp/GtsApp/GtsApp.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/user219905/Documents/GitHub/gts-mobile/GtsApp/GtsApp.iOS/GtsApp.iOS.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/user219905/Documents/GitHub/gts-mobile/GtsApp/GtsApp.Android/GtsApp.Android.csproj
Running restore with 4 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file /Users/user219905/Documents/GitHub/gts-mobile/GtsApp/GtsApp/GtsApp.csproj.
Restoring packages for /Users/user219905/Documents/GitHub/gts-mobile/GtsApp/GtsApp/GtsApp.csproj...
Restoring packages for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/telerik.ui.for.xamarin/index.json
GET [https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id='Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0)
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/telerik.ui.for.xamarin.datagrid/index.json
GET [https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id='Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0)
NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/telerik.ui.for.xamarin.datagrid/index.json 172ms
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/telerik.ui.for.xamarin/index.json 173ms
OK [https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id='Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0) 367ms
OK [https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id='Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin'&semVerLevel=2.0.0](https://nuget.devexpress.com/xRMAAuTIJGNTlKc1O83zlgVKkkr2ibgsDfUBelIIfu3Oq2Ku77/api/FindPackagesById()?id=%27Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin%27&semVerLevel=2.0.0) 502ms
Resolving conflicts for .NETStandard,Version=v2.0...
Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin with version (>= 2022.1.222.1)

- Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2015.3.1202 ]
- Found 0 version(s) in DevExpress
  Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin.DataGrid. No packages exist with this id in source(s): DevExpress, nuget.org
  Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'GtsApp'.

> 

Comment: Where do you get this package from? It is not listed on NuGet.org

Comment: I added a Nuget source to telerik. Login credentials are correct as well. And installing from NugetPackageManager I also get an error that the package could not be found.

Comment: Are you using Nuget Credential Provider or just a NuGet.config with some token inside?

Comment: I am using the credential provider.

Comment: What does the NuGet log actually say?

Comment: Check updated question to view the full log.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct feed? [These docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/installation-and-deployment/telerik-nuget-server#visual-studio-for-mac=) say you should use https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json not nuget.devexpress.com

Comment: Just checked and my source is indeed nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json. I removed all my other nuget sources and the issues still persist.

Comment: Try adding the telerik nuget feed as the first source. The log says the build does not even try to use it which is very odd. It may mean also trust the build uses and old version of your nuget.config file

Comment: I'm having the same issue for a while and cannot find any workaround. I am using the same credentials for Windows and it works without any issue, but I couldn't make it work on the Mac. I have tried to remove all Nuget configs and checked the credentials, source, username, password, and literary everything. No sign of any progress whatsoever! (VS for Mac 17.4.4)